# nodejs authentication token link to secure page

Tags: node.js, authentication, token

I started working on nodeJS token authentication and I encountered a weird issue. Is there any way I can make a link to the restricted page such that user sends Auth token to the server but without encoding it as a GET parameter in the request?
The only way I could solve it is to put the token into the session, but this solution kinda defeats the whole purpose of the token auth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the technology (i.e. node), you want to send it as a header. In CURL, this is as simple as:

`curl --header "token: ASDFASDFASJKDFLKL" http://www.example.com/protected`

Depending on what you're using in node, you'll likely have a request (or req depending on how it's defined) parameter. Your header would be stored in `request.headers`

Comment: I understand how to send a header from server. But that is not quite the problem..
My thing is that suppose I send user auth token, and redirect him to some page. Then user clicks some link, say to go to profile. How do I make <a href> to send auth token?

Comment: What is the problem then? Your question states that you're not sure where to put the token. I suggested the header, showed how to send one, and where you'll likely be able to receive it. Can you beef up your question with existing code samples?

Comment: The client can store store the token in a cookie if you're trying to maintain a client side session.

Comment: So the only way to maintain client side session without using one page system like Angular is to put it in cookies? Actually I think that is what I was looking for! Thanks!